# How to do email field validatation with both a pattern and requiredness?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have used the code below to validate an email field.

```
Email: ko.observable('').extend({ 
    required: { 
        message: 'Email address is required.' 
    }, 
    pattern: { 
        params: "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", 
        message: "Please enter a valid email address" 
    } 
}),
```

Required validation is working when `pattern` is not there. However, I want email to be required *as well as* to follow a specific pattern as mentioned in a regular expression.

It is not working at the moment.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 If you edit, please make sure you fix all obvious issues with a post - otherwise the question might be bumped to the front page with only a minor change.

Answer (score 1):

It works, but your pattern seems wrong, I took one of the internet and it works

http://jsfiddle.net/oefst8fa/

```
var vm = {
email: ko.observable('').extend({ 
    required: true,
    pattern: { 
        params: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/, 
        message: "Please enter a valid email address" 
    } 
})
};
```